# Is it possible to make stockfish promote only to a queen and nothing else?

Tags: engines, pawn-promotion

Is there a way to limit stockfish to promote pawns only to a queen? I'm using python chess library and a stockfish engine. I'm making an engine play itself and then use its moves to control  the robots to play chess in real life. Disabling promotion to anything but a queen would greatly simplify the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid the only way to do this is by modifying SF's code and compiling it. Probably not the hardest task for some competent C++ programmer.